# Spring integration - Gateway - Retry logging

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I have a retry advice applied on a sftpOutboundGateway. I want to see in the logs whenever retries happen. how do I enable that ? is there some property in application.yml ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you talk about an `application.yml`, I just guess that you use Spring Boot. Indeed Spring Boot allows us to configure logging categories in that configuration properties. And here is the one for Spring Retry:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.retry:debug
```

With that you'll see some activities from the `RetryTemplate`:

```
Retry: count=

Checking for rethrow: count=

Retry failed last attempt: count=
```

See Spring Boot docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.logging.log-levels